# Need help figuring out how coefficients are calculated in a 6th degree polynomial.

Tags: matrices, polynomials, summation, regression

so I am currently working on a project for work that takes 700ish data points and uses the LNEST function in Excel to produce a regression of that line. The output from  `y = 2.59846E-14x^6 + -6.4E-11x^5 + 6.2E-8x^4 + -2.9E-5x^3 + 0.00689x^2 + -0.81814x^1 + 918.821` is the result from `=LINEST(K1:K710, J1:J710^{1,2,3,4,5,6})`.

Now I am sort of clueless as to how the values were produced. I looked up LINEST on the MS website and it tells me that it is using the "least squares" method to produce a line that best fits the data. After some research I know somewhat of the least squares method to find a line but I don't know how I would apply that with a 6th degree polynomial? I have the data and end result but I don't know what goes on in between as I need to know this in order to write a program to replicate this process. Here is the data points I am talking about, [Data Points](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bDoQdzfjb6_ytp6eJ22wH0TxUk462BY4PIlPjmdfHNg/edit?usp=sharing)

I have tried to do some math by drawing out a matrix but I have seem to fall short on that one so if you have any insights that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

In you have $n $ data points and a polynomial of degree $6$ then you can use matrices. Let's say the regression function is $y=\beta_0+ \beta_1x^1+\beta_2x^2\beta_3x^3+\beta_4x^4+\beta_5x^5+\beta_6x^6$ and you want to estimate the $7$ parameters $b_j$. Then next we define the following matrices:

$\mathbf y=\begin{bmatrix} y_1\\ y_2\\ y_3 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix},$ $\mathbf X= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \dots & x_1^6 \\ 1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \dots & x_2^6 \\ 1 & x_3 & x_3^2 & \dots & x_3^6 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \dots & x_n^6 \end{bmatrix},$ $\hat b=\begin{bmatrix} \hat \beta_0\\ \hat \beta_1\\ \hat \beta_2\\ \vdots \\ \hat \beta_6 \end{bmatrix}$

Here $\hat \beta_0, \hat \beta_1, ..., \hat \beta_6$ are the estimated coefficients. In your case the number of data points $n=710$. To obtain the estimated parameters use the following matrix formula:

$$\hat b= (\mathbf{X}^\mathsf{T} \mathbf{X})^{-1}\; \mathbf{X}^\mathsf{T} \textbf y$$

$\mathbf{X}^\mathsf{T}$ is the transpose of $\mathbf{X}$ and $(\mathbf{X}^\mathsf{T} \mathbf{X})^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\mathbf{X}^\mathsf{T} \mathbf{X}$.

Comprehensible? Matrix calculation can be well done with Excel. A difficulty maybe is the large number of data points.

For instance, the first row of $\mathbf X$ is $\mathbf X= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 916.405 & 916.405^2 & 916.405^3 & 916.405^4 &916.405^5& 916.405^6 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: AHH that makes sense, as for transpose and the inverse, what do those mean. Isn't transposing a matrix literally mean like flipping it sort of?

Comment: It does depend on what you mean by "flipping it sort of". The transpose of $\mathbf X=\begin{bmatrix}{} 1 & 2 & 3 &  \\ 4 & 5 & 6 &  \\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$ is $\mathbf X^T=\begin{bmatrix}{} 1 & 4 & 7 &  \\ 2 & 5 & 8 &  \\ 3 & 6 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$ You flip the row indices and the column indices. The element $a_{ij}$ becomes the element $a_{ji}$

Comment: Is all comprehensible?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant by "flipping it". But to make sure, I would have a matrix with 7 columns and 710 rows or how many data pairs I have right?

Comment: @StevenVillarreal In this case $\mathbf X$ has 7 columns and 710 rows, while  $\mathbf X^T$ has 710 columns and 7 rows. Thus the matrices have both $710\times 7$. To start you can transpose $X$ with Excel: **=mtrans( J1:J710)**. First you have to [select](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/select-cell-contents-in-excel-23f64223-2b6b-453a-8688-248355f10fa9)  a range of a $7\times 710$. See the link how it works.

Comment: Probably you have to use **=transpose( J1:J710)** instead of **=mtrans( J1:J710)**.

Comment: Awesome, I have done that and have managed to produce a transposed version of my data set. As for the matrix formula that you provided what would 'Y' be? Is that just the numbers 1-710 in its own matrix? How would that even look like?

Comment: @StevenVillarreal Nice, that you´ve managed that. Yes,  $\mathbf y$ is a 710-vector with values from 1 to 710, if these are the y-values: $\mathbf y=\begin{bmatrix}{} 1   \\ 2 \\ 3  \\ \vdots \\ 710 \end{bmatrix}$  I assume that at your sheet that the first columnn contains the y-values and  the second column contains the x-values.